# Sql Automatic Result Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblExample
(
ID int,
Name nvarchar(256),
Date datetime,
IsAnual bit
)
```

This is a simplified example.

Now I scan the next 30 days from `GETDATE()`. If there is result, I insert information into another table:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), Date) <= 30
```

Up to now there is no problem. But

```
WHERE IsAnual = 1
```

I must take into account their continuations. How can I do this?

Suppose that `GETDATE()` is `2013-10-22` and the column contains `2013-10-30`, there is not problem. What if `GETDATE()` is `2014-10-28` and column contains `2013-10-30` AND IsAnual = 1?

Updated:

I found solution. I used recursive query.

```
CREATE TABLE tblExample
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Name nvarchar(256),
Date datetime,
IsAnual bit
)
```

And inserted some rows:

```
INSERT INTO tblExample
(Name, Date, IsAnual)
VALUES
('A', '2012-11-01', 1),
('B', '2013-11-01', 0),
('C', '2013-01-01', 1)
```

And final section is properly working query:

```
WITH TempTable AS
(
SELECT
e.ID, 
e.Name, 
e.Date, 
e.IsAnual
FROM tblExample AS e
UNION ALL
SELECT
e.ID, 
e.Name, 
DATEADD(yy, 1, t.Date),
e.IsAnual
FROM tblExample AS e
INNER JOIN TempTable AS t
ON e.ID = t.ID
WHERE e.IsAnual = 1
AND DATEDIFF(yy, t.Date, DATEADD(yy, 1, GETDATE())) > 0
)
SELECT
*
FROM TempTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), Date) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
```

Results here:

```
14  B   01.11.2013  False
13  A   01.11.2013  True
```

Comment: I read a few times now, still unable to understand what your requirement is. `Getdate()` will only become `2014-10-28` next October.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(),
  CASE
     WHEN IsAnnual = 0 THEN Date
     WHEN IsAnnual = 1 THEN DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,Date,GETDATE()),Date)
  END
) <= 30
```

The expression `DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,Date,GETDATE()),Date)` will give you the date provided in the `Date` column but with its year set to the current year.

I think that's what you were asking for.

It should be noted, however, that the above will not be able to leverage any indexes on `Date`, so may not provide the absolute best performance on a large table.

---

(My initial attempt had the `CASE` expression incorrect, but it's hopefully correct now)

Comment: Thanks this is also my thought. But When considering Date = '2013-01-01' AND GETDATE() = '2013-12-31', this expression will return '2013-01-01' instead of '2014-01-01'. Because I'm scanning next 30 days.

Comment: @Mesut - well, `DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,GETDATE(),Date),GETDATE())` gives you the current date but with it's year portion set the same as the year of `Date` - so you'd do the same thing except you'd do it on the `GETDATE()` part of the `DATEDIFF` rather than the `Date` one. It's not really obvious from the question you've given.

Comment: Your question update is failed. It returnes 0. Also the DATEDIFF() result returns 364

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE DATEDIFF( DAY ,DATEADD(YEAR,(1753 -DATEPART(YEAR ,GETDATE())) *IsAnual ,GETDATE()) ,DATEADD(YEAR ,(1753 -DATEPART(YEAR ,Date)) *IsAnual ,Date)) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
```

Comment: I use 1753 because it is a minimum year in sql datetime.

Comment: Which dates you used?

Comment: Check statement from my answer, that work same with you solution.